# Android - what's wrong with sp?

Tags: android

UI designer drawn this design for Android application:

Size is 1080x1920 px. This is same to Nexus 5 display which has xxhdpi density. In this density 1dp = 3px.
I have this letter on my design JPEG image. Its height - 45px.

[image]

So I calculated my TextView size 45px/3=15sp

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textColor="#5B5C5D"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/tvFolder" />
```

But when I am running my app on Galaxy Nexus - 720x1280px. Density - xhdpi. 1dp = 2px. I am getting this result - my letter 'd' height is 24px which is equal to 12dp.

[image]

Of course, I can recalculate (by multiplying to 1.25) and make TextView 19dp. But I want to understand why this is happening and can we solve this. Maybe I am confused and making a mistake. So my question, what is wrong with sp?

Comment: I couldn't understand what are you trying to do here. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: And what do you mean by "xxhdpi,3x,360dpX640dp"?

Comment: I mean my template(design which I got from UI designer) JPEG file's size is  1080x1920pixels which is equal to 360dpX640dp. 3X means that I should divide my view's size to 3, to get value in sp or dp.

Comment: Is your xml in the main layout folder?

Comment: did you check in your device settings that the font scale is set to 1? If you want to define your font size in device specific pixel, you have to use dp, if you want the user to be able to scale according to his wishes, you use sp.

Comment: @iturki, i edited my question to make more clear. yes, this xml in listitem_folder.xml. I use this layout in my adapter(child of BaseAdapter)

Comment: Try using `dp` as suggested by @Christian .

Comment: I have added it as answer as I think it will solve your issue so you can accept and close the question later.

Comment: @JoeRichard : Don't close this question as it is very normal but important thing that needs to understand while dealing with SP and DP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check in your device settings that the font scale is set to 1?

If you want to define your font size in device specific pixel, you have to use dp, if you want the user to be able to scale according to his wishes, you use sp.

Comment: this 100% right. this should be 45px/3=15dp not in sp. explained in @Christian answer

Comment: so the rate between sp and px is related to user's font preference setting in system setting, and the rate between dp and px is related to the screen desity?

Comment: no, the rate between dp and sp is dependent on the users preference. This allows people with visible handicap to adjust their need. According to the Guidelines, sp is recommended, but if you need a fixed size, you have to use dp.